# Why are these buttons not displaying correctly in larger screen devices? (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have laid out my app in Xcode using iPhone SE view.  The buttons etc all appear under testing how they should.

However when I test in a large screen, i.e iPhone 7 a couple of weird things happen.

1)  Buttons hug the right hand side even though I have the constraints set to be 20px from margins

[image]
[image]

And secondly, a the gradient that I have applied to my buttons seems to stop 3/4 across the button in this instance:

[image]

It is the same code being called in each instance of the buttons:

```
let orangeGradient = CAGradientLayer().orangeButtonColor()
    orangeGradient.frame = self.joinCommunityButton.bounds
    self.joinCommunityButton.layer.insertSublayer(orangeGradient, at: 0)

extension CAGradientLayer {

func bespokeColor() -> CAGradientLayer {

let topColor = UIColor(red: (46/255.0), green: (63/255.0),blue: (81/255.0), alpha: 1)
let bottomColor = UIColor(red: (22/255.0), green: (31/255.0),blue: (41/255.0), alpha: 1)
let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]?

return gradientLayer

}

func orangeButtonColor() -> CAGradientLayer {

    let topColor = UIColor(red: (211/255.0), green: (115/255.0),blue: (28/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: (171/255.0), green: (80/255.0),blue: (14/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]?

    return gradientLayer

}

func purpleButtonColor() -> CAGradientLayer {

    let topColor = UIColor(red: (112/255.0), green: (41/255.0),blue: (183/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: (85/255.0), green: (19/255.0),blue: (159/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]?

    return gradientLayer

}

func greenButtonColor() -> CAGradientLayer {

    let topColor = UIColor(red: (35/255.0), green: (193/255.0),blue: (67/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: (31/255.0), green: (148/255.0),blue: (53/255.0), alpha: 1)
    let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]?

    return gradientLayer

}


}
```

Here is an screenshot of what I believe are the auto layout settings:

[image]

Comment: Where are you applying the gradient layer to the buttons? Has autoLayout taken effect? Make sure you add GradientLayers in `viewDidAppear` **or** define gradient inside `viewDidLoad` and change the bounds of the layer in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Yes i have the first 3 lines of that code (before the extension) in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, `autoLayout` hasn't taken effect yet so your button `bounds` are not device specific.

Put

`orangeGradient.frame = self.joinCommunityButton.bounds` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear`

Make sure to add gradients or perform tasks related to `UIView` frame or bounds **after** `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has been called **if you are using `autoLayout`**.

Also,

Don't put the initialization of the `CAGradientLayer()` inside the `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` functions as they are called multiple times and will keep adding layers to your `UIView`, you should just change the bounds inside the two methods.

Comment: Excellent! That has solved the problem with the gradients being clipped.  Thanks.  I haven't ticket correct answer yet just because I don't want to close the question off with still having an issue with the layout of the buttons hugging the right hand side

Comment: That could possibly be because of the gradient being applied on a width greater than the button width, try setting the `clipsToBounds` property to true of the button in question and check if that solves your problem.

Comment: I've moved the gradient code to the viewDidAppear {} and it's fixed that too.  I think were correct, it wasn't that it was out of position, just the gradient bleeding over the edge. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you are using AutoLayout in interface builder.If you are using then make sure they have left margin too.